# Python-Qt application can not start after cx_Freeze

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml, cx-freeze

I have python/Pyside/qml application.

- like python script - it works
- like *.exe* (builded by cx_freeze) and launched on PC (where the application was born) - it works
- like *.exe* (builded by cx_freeze) and launched on another clean PC, with no installed any python or Qt,... **it does not work** - you can see the error:

***This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initiazed. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.***

[image]

Is there any solution please? I want to .exe which could be launched on ordinary Win10/11 computers.

Comment: Shocking lack of detail. But, you are describing a Qt runtime deployment problem. Make sure you follow all the instructions for deploying a Qt executable correctly.

Comment: Concentrate on the contents of your folder `plugins/platforms` or maybe just folder `platforms` during deployment of you program. I am not cxFreeze expert (never tried it yet) but this exact folder is where your problem is hidden - you are missing `qwindows.dll` in this folder. Maybe you need to copy it there manually before the app freezing.